# Refresh content of variable

Tags: sql, powershell

as mentioned in another posting, i use the possibility to include ps1-parameter-files in scripts like

```
. $PSScriptRoot/ParaFolder/MyParameters.ps1
```

I defined some parameters, which i need frequently and usually don't change. if i'd have to change them, i'm able to do it just in this parameter-file, instead of changing several scripts.
Furthermore i added a variable containing an simple insert-sql statement for logging reasons like:

```
$parafield1 = 'test'
$parafield2 = 'default'
$parafield3 = 'name'
$parafield4 = 'testtest'
$myloggingSQL = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[mytable] 
                           (field1, field2, field3, field4) 
                    VALUES (current_timestamp, '$parafield1', '$parafield2',
                            '$parafield2', '$parafield4')
```

The variables defined above $myloggingSQL should be like default values. So a user doesn't have to fill all of them in his script.

```
$parafield2 = 'userspecifictext'
$parafield4 = 'i am happy today'    
$Command.CommandText = $myloggingSQL 
$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
```

Of course it doesn't work like explained above, as $myloggingSQL will be already filled with the default values, when included.
So i was thinking about to save the insert-statement in another file to be able to work like:

```
. $PSScriptRoot/ParaFolder/MyParameters.ps1
Do calculations and so on...
$parafield2 = 'userspecifictext'
$parafield4 = 'i am happy today'
. $PSScriptRoot/ParaFolder/myLoggingSQLFile.ps1 
$Command.CommandText = $myloggingSQL 
$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
```

When myLoggingSQLFile.ps1 is included the SQL will be filled with the content of the $parafield* variables and finally written in my DB.
But that seems like just a quick&dirty solution out of the mind of a beginner (like me).

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this in an professional way? 
Maybe i am too new to the topic of powershell or just too tired today to find the right and future-proof solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `myloggingSQL` should be a function. If you scope your variables properly you should be able to change them and have the function pick up the new values. They way you're doing it currently the variables are interpolated into the command string when you create it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i'm redesigning my scripts right now as briantist also explained below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should accomplish this with a script module and use a function to generate your query string. To make a module, you put the code into a `.psm1` file, and export what you want to be shared. Then you can use `Import-Module` to bring that into your scripts instead of dot sourcing.

Making a function to return the value of the query string allows you to parameterize it a bit more. By using the the original values as defaults, you can override any of them explicitly.

The contents of your module would look something like this:

```
$parafield1 = 'test'
$parafield2 = 'default'
$parafield3 = 'name'
$parafield4 = 'testtest'

function Get-MyLoggingSql {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [String]
    $Field1 = $parafield1 ,

    [String]    
    $Field2 = $parafield2 ,

    [String]
    $Field3 = $parafield3,

    [String]
    $Field4 = $parafield4
)
    "INSERT INTO [dbo].[mytable] 
                               (field1, field2, field3, field4) 
                        VALUES (current_timestamp, '$Field1', '$Field2',
                                '$Field3', '$Field4')"
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *-*
```

Now in your script, you can do this:

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot/ParaFolder/MyParameters.ps1

$parafield2 = 'userspecifictext'
$parafield4 = 'i am happy today'    
$Command.CommandText = Get-MyLoggingSql -Field2 $parafield2 -Field4 $parafield4
$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
```

Now let's say you're going to override a value for the whole script, and don't want to keep specifying `-Field2` and `-Field4`.

In that case, use [PowerShell's built in `$PSDefaultParameterValues` variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx):

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    "Get-MyLoggingSql:Field2" = 'userspecifictext'
    "Get-MyLoggingSql:Field4" = 'i am happy today'
}
# the above can go at the top of the script

$Command.CommandText = Get-MyLoggingSql
$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
```

Note that this requires PowerShell 3.0+.

Comment: briantist, thanks a lot! that is exactly what i was looking for and will save me a lot of time maintaining my scripts and still keep them as modular and simple as possible. i'm always happy that there are so many helpful people like you!